# JPA table to entity incorrect conversion

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

What I am trying to achieve here is fire an sql query using spring JPA and get entites in return, then transform the objects in ay structure.

The problem is when two tables and entites have the same column, JPA is unable to diffentiate between the vales of those properties and maps wrong values to entities, here is my code:

**DAO**

```
public class EMIDao implements IEMIDao {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<EMI> fetch(Integer month) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                "SELECT DISTINCT e.*, p.*, l.*, i.* FROM emi e JOIN loan l ON l.loan_id = e.loan_id LEFT JOIN product p ON p.product_id = l.product_id LEFT JOIN item i ON i.product_id = p.product_id LEFT JOIN item_return ir ON ir.item_id = i.item_id WHERE e.date = ?1 AND ir.item_return_id IS NULL",
                "EMIProductDTO");
        query.setParameter(1, "2020-" + month + "-16");
        List<Object[]> objects = query.getResultList();

        return EMITransformer.transform(objects);
    }

}
```

**Transformer**

```
public class EMITransformer {

    public static List<EMI> transform(List<Object[]> objects) {
        Map<Integer, EMI> emiMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Product> productMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Loan> loanMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Item> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(objects))
            for (Object[] objectArray : objects) {
                if (ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(objectArray)) {
                    EMI emi = (EMI) objectArray[0];
                    if (!emiMap.containsKey(emi.getId()))
                        emiMap.put(emi.getId(), emi);

                    Product product = (Product) objectArray[1];
                    if (product != null && !productMap.containsKey(product.getId())) {
                        product.setItems(new HashSet<>(0));
                        productMap.put(product.getId(), product);
                    }

                    Loan loan = (Loan) objectArray[2];
                    if (loan != null && !loanMap.containsKey(loan.getId()))
                        loanMap.put(loan.getId(), loan);

                    Item item = (Item) objectArray[3];
                    if (item != null && !itemMap.containsKey(item.getId()))
                        itemMap.put(item.getId(), item);
                }
            }
        itemMap.forEach((id, item) -> {
            productMap.get(item.getProductId()).getItems().add(item);
        });
        loanMap.forEach((id, loan) -> {
            loan.setProduct(productMap.get(loan.getProductId()));
        });
        emiMap.forEach((id, emi) -> {
            emi.setLoan(loanMap.get(emi.getLoanId()));
        });
        return new ArrayList<>(emiMap.values());
    }
}
```

**This is the data I have in my mysql db**

[image: This is the data I have in my db]

**This is the output I get after the db call**

[image]

Its basically confusing price of product with price of item

EMI entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emi")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "EMIProductDTO", entities = { 
        @EntityResult(entityClass = EMI.class),
        @EntityResult(entityClass = Product.class), 
        @EntityResult(entityClass = Loan.class), 
        @EntityResult(entityClass = Item.class) 
})
public class EMI {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "emi_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "loan_id")
    private Integer loanId;
    @Column(name = "principal")
    private Integer principal;
    @Column(name = "interest")
    private Integer interest;
    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Timestamp createdOn;
    @Transient
    private Integer emi;
    @Transient
    private Loan loan;
```

**Product Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "ProductItemDTO", entities = { @EntityResult(entityClass = Product.class),
        @EntityResult(entityClass = Item.class) })
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "order_number")
    private String orderNumber;
    @Column(name = "product_type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "price")
    private Integer price;
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Timestamp createdOn;
```

**Item Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brand;
    @Column(name = "price")
    private Integer price;
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Integer productId;
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Timestamp createdOn;
```

Every thing is working as expected, I cannot change the approach to using the onetoonemapping annotations , just want jpa to map the price fields properly any help is highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried aliasing the columns? p.price as product_price, i.price as item_price ....

Comment: Then I will have to specify every column in the query, i am looking more on the lines of hibernate addEntity >>  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm